# OpenVPN on openSUSE 12.2 bridge not working

Tags: openvpn, opensuse

I would like to ask for a little help. I'm setting up a openvpn bridge in opensuse 12.2, I can connect to server, but I can't ping the server, nor anything that is behind server. Also, I can't ping the client from server. So far what I have done is:

I have two NICs, eth0 and eth1.

eth0 is external network

eth1 is internal network

In Yast I've added br0 and tap0 interfaces, in br0 I've added eth1 and tap0 to the bridge and set IP 192.168.10.1/24

In firewall

eth0 - external zone

eth1, tap0, br0 - internal zone

Thank you very much for your help! :)

server route -n

```
 Kernel IF routing table
Destination Gateway     Genmask     Flags Metric    Ref Use If ace
0.0.0.0     192.168.42.2    0.0.0.0     UG  0   0   0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0     255.0.0.0   U   0   0   0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0 U   0   0   0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U   0   0   0 brO
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U   0   0   0 eth0
```

sorry for the mess, this is my first post:) thank you!

Comment: I think a a route -n on both the client and server would be useful after the connect.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't know what has happened, but now it works and I've done nothing:)